# open on-screen keyboard causes toolbar to scroll out of sight

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

In one of our `Activity`s scrolling is broken when the on-screen keyboard pops up.

If the content fits on the screen and no keyboard is visible the `Activity` looks like this:

[image: View with closed keyboard]

If the keyboard is open and the user enters a few lines, the toolbar begins to scroll out of sight:

[image: Keyboard open with content underneath status & toolbar]

At some point the toolbar is completely gone:

[image: Keyboard open with content even more underneath status & toolbar]

If the keyboard is not open scrolling works fine:

[image: Scrolling without keyboard works fine]

The `Activity` contains only a `FrameLayout`, everything else is provided by a `Fragment`.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/task_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".TaskDetailActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

The `Fragment` uses a `CoordinatorLayout` and looks like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="0dp" >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >

            <org.dmfs.tasks.widget.TaskView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize" >

                <org.dmfs.tasks.widget.TextFieldView
                    android:id="@+id/task_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:paddingEnd="48dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="48dp"
                    android:paddingRight="48dp"
                    android:paddingStart="48dp"
                    app:fieldDescriptor="@id/task_field_title" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:autoLink="none"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1"
                        android:maxLines="3"
                        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                        android:textColorLink="#d0ffffff"
                        android:textSize="28sp" >
                    </TextView>
                </org.dmfs.tasks.widget.TextFieldView>

                <org.dmfs.tasks.widget.TimeFieldView
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    style="@style/task_widget"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingEnd="56dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="56dp"
                    android:paddingStart="56dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:fieldDescriptor="@id/task_field_due" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@android:id/text1"
                        style="@style/field_view_text_value"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_tab_due"
                        android:drawablePadding="12dp"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_tab_due"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:includeFontPadding="false"
                        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                        android:textSize="18sp" >
                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@android:id/text2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffffff" >
                    </TextView>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/buttons"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="gone" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/button_add_one_day"
                            style="@style/time_forward_button"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_detail_delay_1d"
                            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_detail_delay_1d"
                            android:text="@string/button_add_one_day"
                            android:textColor="#a0ffffff" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/button_add_one_hour"
                            style="@style/time_forward_button"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                               android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_detail_delay_1h"
                            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_detail_delay_1h"
                            android:text="@string/button_add_one_hour"
                            android:textColor="#a0ffffff" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </org.dmfs.tasks.widget.TimeFieldView>
            </org.dmfs.tasks.widget.TaskView>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_complete" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The `@+id/content` `LinearLayout` is populated at runtime.

We have another Activity that uses neither `CoordinatorLayout` nor a `Toolbar`, but a `ScrollView` instead and which shows exactly the same symptoms. You can see it here: https://github.com/dmfs/opentasks/blob/master/res/layout/activity_task_editor.xml and https://github.com/dmfs/opentasks/blob/master/res/layout/fragment_task_edit_detail.xml

We use the following dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Any hint what could cause this is appreciated.

Comment: In your Androidmanifest.xml try this:
activity name="yourActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: `adjustPan` doesn't fix it. It looks slightly different now, but the problem is still the same. Though it's a good hint, I need to look into `android:windowSoftInputMode`

Comment: @Nik thanks for the hint. "adjustResize" actually fixed it.